# cURL getting HEAD takes too long for multiple URLs

Tags: php, curl

i have this cURL setup here

```
function curl($url) {
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_exec($ch);
 $ct = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
 return $ct;
}
```

i use it to get the `Content-Type` and return this value to the user. Just to ease things to people who wants to check if all their URLs are valid links or not or Valid images links or not.

so my code is

```
if(isset($_POST['urls'])) {
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        echo "Content Type is ".curl($url)."<br>";
    }
}
```

My problem is that if the user entered `100 URL ~ 500 URL` it takes `10s ~ 15s` to finish the function.

How can i optimize the function, And is it slow because of my internet connection speed only?

Would it be used for `DDoS` attacks and it is better to remove it?

Comment: Parallelize it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php

Comment: (And yes, this could conceivably be used for DDoS. Consider rate limiting your users if you're making this available to the general untrustworthy public.)

Comment: @ceejayoz if user can put `500 URL` for multiple times, And repeat and repeat, Is that pretty bad? (Limit: 500)

Comment: Yes, it's potentially bad. They could open up a hundred tabs, or automate it, and cause you to send millions of HTTP requests to a victim server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

15ms is pretty damn fast for an operation like that! It is possible to optimize it with the curl_multi functions, as these functions allow urls to be loaded in parallel.
However, I'm not super sure why you would care if it's 15ms. It's often assumed that a singe HTTP requests is more than that.

Comment: I'd guess they mean 10-15 seconds. Sequentially doing 500 URLs in 15ms in this manner is, IMO, impossible.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes, `s` not `ms` sorry about that mistake.